# Qu'est-ce qu'un roman phénoménologique ?

Tags: vocabulaire, philosophie, littérature

Je lisais *Voyage au bout de la nuit* puis son étude de texte ("profil d'une œuvre") et il est dit que Céline écrit un livre phénoménologique et que c'est un des premiers du genre.

Il y a quelques explications derrière mais très peu et je ne comprends pas vraiment ce dont il pourrait être question ; des exemples ? (de ce texte ou d'une manière plus générale) Merci !

Comment: (Oui, la question a certainement sa place ici.) As-tu cherché une définition dans un dico, par exemple dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ph%C3%A9nom%C3%A9nologique) ?

Comment: Eléments de réponse : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ph%C3%A9nom%C3%A9nologie_(philosophie) (i.e : courant philosophique qui se concentre sur l'étude des phénomènes, de l’expérience vécue et des contenus de conscience).

Comment: Il me semble que ce n'est pas une question de langue, mais de philosophie. Cela n'ôte rien à son intérêt évidemment, juste pour dire que ce n'est probablement pas le lieu adéquat pour la poser.

Comment: @mansuetus Merci pour les réponses, j'ai lu les définitions et ainsi de suite mais je ne comprends toujours pas vraiment, j'ai l'impression que tous les romans qui dépeignent des faits le sont (émile zola, ...).

Comment: @Thomas C'est l’expérience plus que les faits décrits qui est au centre du roman de ce que j'en comprend.

Comment: Émile Zola se sert des faits en toile de fond d'une histoire, alors que dans le nouveau roman (auquel est associé étroitement la phénoménologie) l'histoire a peu d'importance, la description passe au premier plan.

Comment: A mon sens s'il y a un roman qui a privilégié l'étude de l'âme à celle de la réalité (notions que d'ailleurs il oppose), peut-être même plus que le *Voyage*, que pourtant j'admire, c'est *A la recherche du temps perdu*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En art ou en littérature, il arrive qu'on parle d'un style "phénoménologique" pour insister sur le fait que l'auteur cherche à mettre en évidence une conscience, un flux de sensations personnelles, sans chercher à s'intéresser à l'objet de ses sensations.

Par exemple, dans le cas du Voyage au bout de la nuit, le roman tout entier n'est qu'une succession de sensations, d'impressions, de perceptions de Bardamu. En disant qu'il s'agit d'un roman "phénoménologique", on veut dire que ce roman est très loin des romans naturalistes de Zola, par exemple. Zola cherche à montrer comment la conscience des hommes s'étudie comme on étudierait un objet quelconque (un arbre, un mouton, le mouvement d'une planète) : il veut savoir comment les hommes réagissent à des manipulations extérieures (la mort d'un proche, un drame familial). En résumé, Zola s'intéresse aux hommes dans leur environnement, ce qui nécessite d'étudier les deux.
Si l'on adopte une attitude phénoménologique, on s'intéressera plutôt à ce qui se passe en nous, et rien de plus. Dans l'exemple de Céline, on ne va pas se poser de questions sur le pourquoi du comment de la guerre, sur l'origine du mal qui pousse les hommes à s'enterrer dans des tranchées, etc. ; on va juste voir qu'il y a une guerre, se trouver trimballé entre la nuit et le jour, voir des gens mourir. 
C'est pour cela que *Voyage au bout de la nuit* donne parfois l'impression que Bardamu évolue dans un monde décousu, sans beaucoup de sens. C'est parce que Céline ne cherche pas à reconstruire le monde à partir de ce que Bardamu vit : il cherche juste à montrer ce que Bardamu vit.

Voilà, j'espère avoir été clair. L'expression est parfois rencontrée en littérature (certains l'ont dit de Claude Simon mais je n'ai plus la source). Elle ne devrait pas être trop répandue, parce que la phénoménologie désigne surtout une théorie un peu compliquée dont la vocation n'est pas d'étudier les arts mais plutôt le processus par lequel nous pouvons acquérir des connaissances (i.e., par la conscience des phénomènes).

Answer (score 0):

Je me permets un début de réponse.Une fois la définition lue : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ph%C3%A9nom%C3%A9nologie, on peut comprendre qu'il s'agit d'une étude, de l'écriture d'un texte, dont la structure est déduite de l'analyse d'un fait, d'un personnage réel.

D'après l'étude de ce livre : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_au_bout_de_la_nuit, l'auteur s'inspire directement d'un personnage réel, Ferdinand Bardamu, qui confirme la structure sur base d'un personnage réel (cependant il s'agit bien d'un roman, et non comme on aurait tendance à penser, à une biographie).

De plus, toujours d'après la défintion, la Phénoménologie suggère une réalité multiple. Simple **hypothèse** de ma part mais on peut voir dans le [style](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_au_bout_de_la_nuit#Style) utilisé, la volonté de l'auteur de mêler l'argot, le franc parlé avec un langage soutenu qui pourrait confirmer cette idée de vision du monde avec une réalité multiple. Le narrateur se retrouve donc plongé dans le monde qu'il décrit mais en tant que narrateur il se doit d'utiliser un style soutenu (ce qui renforce l'idée de réalité multiple).